# Upload .csv Data to specific sheet of a Google Sheet using PyDrive

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, pydrive

So far I've managed to make a python script using PyDrive to a new Google Sheet, using:

```
myfile = drive.CreateFile({
    "id": "IDHERE"
})


myfile.SetContentFile('FILENAME.csv')
myfile.Upload()
```

However, ideally I'd like to be able to specify not only the spreadsheet ID to upload to, but the GID of the specific sheet in the spreadsheet to add the information to.

Does anyone know if this is possible?